# how to set the data retrieved from the database as the div content?

Tags: javascript, listview, cordova

coding for retrieving data..

**script**

```
 function querySuccess(tx, results) 
            {
                    var len = results.rows.length;
                    console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
                    for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
                    {
                        console.log("Row = " + i + " name= " + results.rows.item(i).name+ " address=  " + results.rows.item(i).address+ " roll_no= " + results.rows.item(i).roll_no);
                        document.getElementById("list_view").innerhtml  = results.rows.item(i).name;
                    }
            }
```

**html**

```
 <div id="list_view" style="float:left; width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
                <ul style="float:left; width:100%; list-style:none; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
                    <div style=" border-bottom-color:#CCCCCC; border-bottom:ridge; "> <li style="font-size:18px"></li></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**AM I CORRECT??**
**how to set the data retrieved from the database as the div content?**

Comment: _"AM I CORRECT?"_ - Well what happened when you tried it? (I'm guessing it didn't work, because you're setting the incorrectly lowercase `innerhtml` property of the same element on each loop iteration - each iteration needs to add to the content, not overwrite it.)

Comment: Use innerHTML not innerhtml

Comment: Setting the innerHTML to something arbitrary is asking for trouble. And this will keep overwriting the same element inside the loop.

Comment: nnnnnn, Prasath K,i used innerHtml and textContent....i could not see any output.the place where the content had to come it was empty...

Comment: it's innerHTML .... Not innerhtml or innerHtml

Comment: nnnnnn,Jack,Prasath K..i get your point..thank you.now,i have changed the flow of the project.so,prior to this **i need to pass an array from 1 html to another html page**, only after that,i can check this.
..i will try it out. and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("list_view").innerhtml  = results.rows.item(i).name;
```

becomes

```
document.getElementById("list_view").innerHTML  = results.rows.item(i).name;
```

P.S. i see

```
<divid="list_view"...>
```

maybe it's only an accidental error here on SO, but try to check if 'id' is separated from 'div' and not 'divid'

Comment: Alberto Fecchi,thank you,i will check it out!!..yeah,i noticed it and changed it.

Comment: Alberto Fecchi,it worked!!...can you tell me how should we add features to the text such as **BOLD, text-align:center** AND ALL...??i have all these at the RESPECTIVE TAGS,but it does not take in this property.....

**i am yet to try it out for the list view**